# How do I install linux ODBC driver for IBM iSeries?

Tags: odbc, ibm-midrange

Been following instructions here: 
http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/linux/guide.html

Trying to install in CentOS instance after installing unixODBC. Installed all dependencies except libodbcinst.so.1, libodc.so.1 and libXm.so.3 which yum does not find but the first two appear when calling whereis.